# Change font size using Integer not string

Tags: javascript, html, svg, javascript-objects

I am currently working on SVG text. I am trying to change fontSize dynamically. However it isn't working

It let me change the font size by doing the following

```
this.text.style.fontSize = "xx-small";
```

or 
x-small, small, medium, large, x-large, xx-large

However, what I actuall want to do is

```
this.text.style.fontSize = 30;
```

or 
any other integer (20, 12, etc) but it won't let me do that.

I want to be able to pass the fontSize using a value not string

The actual function is

```
function setSize (textSize) {
    this.text.style.fontSize = textSize;

    //this.text.style.fontSize = "xx-small"; //this works
    //this.text.style.fontSize = 10; // this doesn't work
}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure about svg, but you may have to specify a measuring unit. Meaning, 30 what? (px, vm, em, etc.)

Comment: When I am adding the integer value in Inspect Element -> Inspector using Firefox it works. However, when trying to do it dynamically as shown above then it the value has to be passed in strings i.e. "30px" or "x-large" etc. However, I really need to make it work so it takes value like 30 etc without strings (quotes). If you know what I mean?

Comment: this.text.setAttribute ("font-size",textSize)

Comment: Or this.text.style.fontSize = textSize + "px"

Comment: @HolgerWill using this.text.style.fontSize = textSize + "px" has solved the problem and it works as I want it to. I wish I figured that one out before. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try mention it as "30px" or "30cm" or in percentage as "30%"

Comment: Hi, by doing "30px" works Thanks. However, that still doesn't solve my problem as I want to add as a integer value like 1, 2, 20, 30 not "1px" or "30px" in strings.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer Well have your function take a number, then just append the proper metric with your function that way you don't have to specify it when you call the function. This will only work if you are consistently going to use one metric. If you're using multiple metrics, you'll have to pass something into your function to let it know which to use.